# Extract nth Occurance Number from String

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula

I have a column containing cells of text string which includes text and numbers. I found a great formula that finds the first number in the string and extracts it to the corresponding cell e.g.

Text String: "Initial commission of Â£9,999.99, then renewal commission of Â£9.9 from month 99"

Entering this formula `=LOOKUP(99^99,--("0"&MID(F8,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},F8&"0123456789")),ROW($1:$10000))))` adjacent to the cell will extract the first number of 9,999.99.

This is not my formula but one that I found and love but would like to be able to indicate that I would also like to extract the 2nd occurring number and also the 3rd occurring number. Basically all the numbers in the string, into separate cells.

Are any of you clever people able to suggest an edit on the formula to allow this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you orginal text is in say A1 and the first stripped out number shows up in B1. in C1 you could use the SUBSTITUTE function and substitute "" into the A1 text wherever the value in B1 is found.  Then in D1, repeat your formula to pull out the first number except this time the text you are pulling from is in C1.  repeat this process as you go right and eventually you will have all the numbers in their own cells.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was one option I thought of but was trying to avoid extra columns to make it work as it will form part of an automated process to eventually import into an access db.

Comment: you can always toss some of the intermediate columns way of to the right in an area that is not used as an option.  You should be able to move them after you have your formulas set up.  when you are done rearranging columns, only the number columns would be side by side.

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of numbers that would appears in a sentence?  This may be something better suited for VBA to go through the extraction.

Comment: The max would 3 numbers

Comment: I'm thinking that VBA would be the easier option once it gets to extracting two or more separate numbers form a string

Comment: you want the numbers in adjacent columns or adjacent rows?

Comment: your formula seems to return **the first digit** of the first number which is 9,999.99.  I thought it was returning the whole first number which is 9,999.99  Big difference.  I believe with a coma for your thousands separator and . for your decimal VBA will be the better approach for grabbing whole numbers.

Comment: @TomSharpe  ALL YOURS!  I do not code VBA well.

Comment: It's returning all digits of the first number for me.
Maybe I need to sleep on it as I have been over thinking it.

Comment: I would do it using the same method as in the formula, i.e. start from a digit and keep appending characters to it until the result is no longer a number. Tricky to know what to do about plus/minus signs/hyphens in general case though. A bit busy so might not be until tomorrow, happy if anyone else wants to do a VBA solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

So this is the proposed function - it uses a simple 2-state approach. The problem with a general solution is with using a comma both as a thousands separator and part of the text as in the question. So 999,999 could be a single number or two separate numbers. Also, 99,99,99 although not a valid number returns TRUE from ISNUMERIC and 99 from VAL. You could try and find the longest possible number but if faced with a string such as 99,999,99 you would have to backtrack and a simple 2-state model wouldn't work.

So I think the only practical solution at this kind of simple level is for the function to be called with a parameter which tells it either (a) to treat a comma as a thousands separator (and basically ignore it) or (b) to treat it as a delimiter and therefore to stop adding characters to a number whenever a comma is encountered.

It should be easy enough to be able to process an initial minus sign if required, but that isn't in the present version yet.

```
Function GetNthNumber(s As String, n As Integer, Optional CommaAsThousands As Boolean = True) As Variant

Dim c, testNumber, number As String

' Ignore commas if treated as thousands separator
If CommaAsThousands Then s = Replace(s, ",", "")

s = s & "x"

Dim i, j, count As Integer

Dim inNumber As Boolean

inNumber = False

' Loop through each character of string

For i = 1 To Len(s)

c = Mid(s, i, 1)

' Part of a number - append new character or finish number

    If inNumber Then
        If IsNumeric(number & c) And (CommaAsThousands Or c <> ",") Then
            number = number & c
        Else
            inNumber = False
            If count = n Then Exit For
        End If
    Else

' Not part of a number - start new number or do nothing

        If IsNumeric(c) Then
            inNumber = True
            number = c
            count = count + 1
        End If

    End If
Next i

'Return nth number or #Value error

If count = n Then
    GetNthNumber = Val(number)
Else
    GetNthNumber = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End If
End Function
```

Here are the results when called in the two different ways (first row with comma as thousands separator and second row with comma as delimiter):-

[image]

Comment: Thanks @tom-sharpe I'll try have a play with it today but it may have to wait until next week.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to sort it out in the end with a crazy long formula.
Its not the prettiest of formulas but it does the job.

Thank you for your suggestiongs to which did lead me down the trail of thought to get the answer. Here are my formulas.

The string of text is in a table column called 'Event Label' formula reference [@[Event Label]].

So for the first number I use this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT([@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]])+1)),LEFT([@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]])+1)),LOOKUP(99^99,--("0"&MID(LEFT([@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]])+1)),MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},LEFT([@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]])+1))&"0123456789")),ROW($1:$10000)))))
```

For the second number I use this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT([@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]]))),RIGHT([@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]]))),LOOKUP(99^99,--("0"&MID(RIGHT([@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]]))),MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},RIGHT([@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]],FIND("Â",[@[Event Label]])))&"0123456789")),ROW($1:$10000)))))
```

And for the final 3rd number I use this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT([@[Event Label]],LEN([@[Event Label]])-FIND("month",[@[Event Label]])+1),RIGHT([@[Event Label]],LEN([@[Event Label]])-FIND("month",[@[Event Label]])+1),LOOKUP(99^99,--("0"&MID(RIGHT([@[Event Label]],LEN([@[Event Label]])-FIND("month",[@[Event Label]])+1),MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},RIGHT([@[Event Label]],LEN([@[Event Label]])-FIND("month",[@[Event Label]])+1)&"0123456789")),ROW($1:$10000)))))
```

This works for me as I have defined text strings that will always be in the same position in the text string.

I'm sure there is probably a better way but it will do for now.