# Parsing or extracting text from a single cell in a spreadsheet

Tags: string, excel, parsing, google-sheets, excel-formula

Here is what I'm trying to do:

Starting with a cell that has something like "receipt 28.19 walmart"  or "receipt 117.58 amazon", I would like to be able to extract the dollar amount to a different cell. So a function that will put 28.19 and 117.58 in each cell, respectively.

I know you can use the MID function to extract part of a string of text if you know where it starts and how long it is, but the problem here is it could be different lengths. For example, the 28.19 is length 5, but the 117.58 is length 6, so I couldn't use MID to always get the total dollar amount because the length of the desired substring is not always the same.

If anyone knows a solution to this, please respond.  Also, if there is a solution for it that works in google spreadsheets, that would be acceptable as well. I'm assuming a lot of the functions are the same from excel to google sheets.

Comment: You can still determine the length of the numbers if you know the length of the textual strings ie if its always "receipt *.## [store]". You can just calculate the length by subtracting the total amount of text characters (if known) from the total length of the cell string. Not sure what else to add here. What have you tried for formulas?

Comment: A very neat formula is quoted in this question - not sure where it came from originally http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721709/extract-nth-occurance-number-from-string/37730872#37730872 (no-one liked my VBA effort!) but as mentioned you could simplify it massively if it always has 'receipt' in front and a space afterwards.

Comment: See below for a suuuuper easy formula for google sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the number between the two blank space in the string given in the cell. So, for string like "receipt 2356.14789 amazon", we have to find pos of blanks.

Now, to find the position of nth space in a string we can use these formulas

```
1st Position : =find(" ",a1)
2nd Position : =find(" ",a1,find(" ",a1)+1)
3rd Position : =find(" ",a1,find(" ",a1,find(" ",a1)+1)+1)
...........
Nth position : =find(" ",a1,find(" ",a1,find(" ",a1,find(" ",a1,......n-1 times find(" ",a1)+1)+1)+1.....n-1 times +1)
```

So, using above formula finding first and second blank in the string :

The values we have 8 and 19 in B1 and C1 are the positions of the blank spaces in the string. Now our desired result need to be, let string be s then

```
s with removal of "receipt " & " amazon"
```

Now we can use the MID function to get the output.
MID function : `=MID(text,start_num,num_chars)`
returns the character from the middle of a text string, given a starting position and length.

So, we have starting position i.e first blank position(8), we have to calculate the num_chars i.e the length.

To calculate length we have to do following calculation :

```
subtract the len of "amazon" from total len of string
length of substring s2 : =len(a1)- FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1) which is second blank pos.

add len of sub string1 and sub string2
s2 + FIND(" ",A1)
```

Now, using mid function we will get,

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),F1,(LEN S1+ LEN S2))
```

Now trim this value since it will be containing a blank space in start of "receipt ".

```
=trim(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),F1,(LEN S1+ LEN S2)))
```

[image]

So, final formula is below :

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+FIND(" ",A1)))
```

2nd Method :

Use Delimit with select space. Shortcut ALT-> A->A->E , delimit select space , next then enter.

[image]

Output :

[image]

Comment: Good call on the text to columns. It's also nice because then you have the three (or however many) categories split for you quickly, then you could sort them, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I knew about the text to columns thing, but was looking for a way to do it automatically as new values are entered.  Awesome explanation, and I'm finding there are many ways to get to the same result (both from your answer and others).  Either way it has been a learning experience in how to implement a formula like this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee that the format is `[word][space][number][space][word]`, then this should work:

[From here](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-nth-word-from-text-string):

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))), (2-1)*LEN(A1)+1, LEN(A1)))`

Where `A1` has "`receipt 28.19 walmart`"

Comment: This is a great formula!  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Really, a great formula, its working for all situation with format [string][blank][numeric][blank][string] to extract the num part.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.  Take a look at how I went step by step to find the answer.  `=MID(A3,SEARCH(" ",A3)+1,SEARCH(" ",MID(A3,SEARCH(" ",A3)+1,LEN(A3)))-1)`.  If you want to learn more, checkout this free lesson [Len(), Search(), Trim()](http://www.cruter.com/u/n9l) (link expires in 10 days).

[image: Cruter complex formula writing... step by step]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way and my personal favorite method of doing this is using regex extract:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT ("YOUR TEXT", "\D+(\d+\.?\d+)\D+?")
```

This is basically saying your string starts  with any number of non digit characters `\D+`  followed by some digits `\d+` , which may or may not include a decimal with another digit , possibly followed by more non digit characters

The parentheses around the digit patterns are what directs it to extract that value only

Note this is for Google sheets specifically since you said you were also wanting one on there

[image]

If you need to be able to sum your extracted text you can just wrap it in value:

```
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT (A1 , "\D+(\d+\.?\d+)\D+?"))
```

OR for even MORE convenience if you have a whole column of values you can enter a single formula that will run your regex all the way down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(O1:O)>0,VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT (O1:O , "\D+(\d+\.?\d+)\D+?")),))
```

[image]

Comment: Your formula returns a string.  If the OP needs a numeric value, you may convert in various ways -- Precede with double unary; precede with `1*` or `0+`, use the `VALUE` function, etc.

Comment: Also, assuming the first digit will always be the start of the price, you could simplify to `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`, or you could make the price string have a mandatory two decimals, if needed.

Comment: I personally would still keep the decimal as optional in case you end up with a flat rate for something also not sure if there is ever quantity listed in the item name